# 8086 assembly code bug

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Hello i try to run that routine but it halted.
When start AX=4B5B, this code supposed to convert AL content in it's ASCII counterpart and store it in the RESULT variable.
I've just start assembly so bee kind please, and if someone can help me thx in advance.

```
ASSUME  CS:Code, DS:Data
Data    SEGMENT
RESULT  DB 3 DUP(?)
Data    ENDS

Code    SEGMENT
Debut:  MOV BX,   offset RESULT
        MOV AH,   AL

QuartH: MOV CL,   4
        SHR AH,   CL
        AND AH,   0FH
        CMP AH,   0AH
        JAE AlphaH
        ADD AH,   '0'
        JMP FinH
AlphaH: ADD AH,   'A'
        SUB AH,   0AH
FinH:   MOV [BX], AH

QuartL: AND AL,   0FH
        CMP AL,   0AH
        JAE AlphaL
        ADD AL,   '0'
        JMP FinL
AlphaL: ADD AL,   'A'
        SUB AL,   0AH
FinL:   MOV Byte ptr[BX+1], AL

FinCH:  MOV Byte ptr[BX+2], '$'
Code    ENDS
        END  Debut
```

Comment: Just wondering...where's your RET?

Comment: (And for reference, code this simple won't crash any even halfway decent emulator.  You'd do well to assume the error is in your own code until you can say with confidence that there are no errors.)

Comment: I always assume my coding errors(trust me) but this code is not mine ;-) and I'm just learning assembly it's why I ask if it can be an emulator problem.

Comment: Well, i'm about 98% certain that you need a RET (or RETF or IRET, depending on how this code will be called) at the end of this subroutine.

Comment: *"Maybe it's a bug in the emu8086 emulator"* No.

Comment: "this code is not mine" Well, get your money back! :) You say `assume ds:Data` but you don't make it so. Plus, as cHao points out, you don't exit properly. I'd go with `int 20h` rather than `retf`, but exit some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: make sure DS is pointing at your data segment. It's not by default in DOS EXE programs, unless you are using the tiny model. So, at the beginning of your code, add this:

```
MOV AX,data
MOV DS,AX
```

Second: this routine needs a `RET` at the end, if this is meant to be called from another part of your program. I guess this is not what you are doing, and we are seeing your entire program. If it's the case, then you have to end with

```
MOV AX,4C00h
INT 21h
```

To return to DOS.

And... well, you build a $-terminated string so you want to print it, don't you? Use DOS function `09h` for that:

```
MOV DX,offset RESULT
MOV AH,9
INT 21h
```

You can even skip the part in which your code adds the `$`, if you put it straight in your `RESULT` variable. Something like this:

```
RESULT   db 32,32,13,10,'$'
```

This provides you for room for two hex digits (initialized to space characters), plus carriage return and line feed, in case you want to print this string, and the terminating `$`